# How to check if there are available data to read before to call recv in a blocking socket context on Windows PCs

Tags: c, windows, sockets

I wrote a short TCP client application to test a SW broker  using blocking sockets. It works well and I am happy with it. Now I need to modify it and I have a problem reading not solecited messages (messages coming from the server not initiated by the client) because recv() blocks the program flow until there is no data to read.
Good solution for me may be to find a way to check if there are available data to read before calling recv() or that recv() may exit if there are no data to read within a certain period.
So I tried with this function:

```
static bool isDataAvailable(int socket)
{
   fd_set sready;
   struct timeval nowait;

   FD_ZERO(&sready);
   FD_SET((unsigned int) socket, &sready);
   memset((char *) &nowait, 0, sizeof(nowait));

   bool res = select(socket + 1, &sready, NULL, NULL, &nowait);
   if(FD_ISSET(socket, &sready))
      res = true;
   else
      res = false;
   return res;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

but the result is that after the call all my application works as I selected to work using non blocking sockets. I normally use it on Linux and it works. I found some info around the web about select() and seems to me it would work also under Windows. But... something is going wrong.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks,
Massimo

Comment: How do you use this function? What behavior did you expect? If you only call `recv` after this function returns `true`, then of course your program will (in a way) behave like the socket was non-blocking, you don't call the `recv` function which does the blocking.

Comment: Also, don't forget to check for errors from `select`.

Comment: Well... I would expect select returns a positive value if there are available data to read calling recv(). If selects returns a negative value may be a select error or the socket is closed. So, I started as simple as possible to see it working or not just in case of no data available.

Comment: Yes, sure, I can check better select errors at least now to understand how to implement my function.

Comment: `select()` will return `> 0` if the socket is readable, 0 on timeout, and -1 on error. So, since you are only checking 1 socket, you can do this instead: `return select(...) > 0;`